# Draw a vertical line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows, graphs

I drew a graph like this in latex. but I need to add that vertical line with numbers too. how can I add it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \begin{center}
    \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
    [xshift=-3cm,ultra thick,node distance=1cm]
      \node[rednode](c1)[xshift=0cm]{$5$};
        \node[rednode](c2)[xshift=3cm]{$4$};
    \node[rednode](r1)[xshift=+2cm,yshift=+4cm]{$7$};
    \node[rednode](r2)[xshift=-2cm,yshift=3cm]{$6$};
    \node[rednode](r3)[xshift=-5.4cm,yshift=-3cm]{${3}$};    
    \node[rednode](r4)[xshift=0cm,yshift=-4cm]{${2}$};    
    \node[rednode](r5)[xshift=5cm,yshift=-5cm]{${1}$};
    \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (c2);
    \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (r3);
    \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (r4);
    \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r1);
    \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r3);
    \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r4);
    \draw[<->,black] (r3)-- (r4);
    \draw[<->,black] (r3)-- (c1);
    \draw[<->,black] (r4)-- (r5);
    \draw[<->,black] (r5)-- (c1);
    \draw[<->,black] (r5)-- (c2);
    \draw[->,black](r3)edge[in=-20,out=60,loop below]node[below right]{}();
    \draw[->,black](r5)edge[in=-20,out=60,loop below]node[below right]{}();
    \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{ }
     \label{}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeXExchange. Please provide a minimal working example (MWE). For more, read this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Quite simple: draw arrow at left edge of current bounding box and add ticks as ou show on image. For an answer, You need to provide an MWE.

Comment: I have added an MWE. sorry! but how can add that arrow at the left edge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you already know all you need to make a line like that. You know how to add nodes, and you know how to draw arrows between nodes (or coordinates). There doesn't have to be anything more to it.

But there are other techniques one can use to (possibly) simplify things, such as using a for-loop to draw the numbers next to the line. Below I used a loop both to draw the connections in the graph, and the numbers next to the line.

I also didn't use `xshift` and `yshift`, specifying instead the coordinates of the nodes directly. (Seems more natural to me, but probably mainly a matter of personal preference.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        ultra thick,
        node distance=1cm,
        rednode/.style={fill=red!20,circle,draw=red} % placeholder style
        ]

    \node[rednode] (c1)               {$5$};
    \node[rednode] (c2) at (3,0)      {$4$};
    \node[rednode] (r1) at (2,4)      {$7$};
    \node[rednode] (r2) at (-2,3)     {$6$};
    \node[rednode] (r3) at (-5.4, -3) {$3$};    
    \node[rednode] (r4) at (0,-4)     {$2$};    
    \node[rednode] (r5) at (5,-5)     {$1$};
    
    \foreach \x/\y in {r1/c2,r1/r3,r1/r4,
                       r2/r1,r2/r3,r2/r4,
                       r3/r4,r3/c1,
                       r4/r5,
                       r5/c1,r5/c2}
          \draw [<->] (\x) -- (\y);                       
                       
    % loop below sets the in and out angles
    \draw[->] (r3) edge[loop below] ();
    \draw[->] (r5) edge[loop below] ();
    
    \draw [->] (-6,-6) -- +(0,11) node[left, font=\Large] {$s$};
    
    % specify the y-values where you want numbers on the axis here
    \foreach [count=\i] \y in {-5,-2,1,4}
        \node[left=5pt,font=\Large] at (-6,\y) {$\i$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not show the graph you provided. I also do not know what `rednode` does. Since you already connected nodes with arrows, I am not sure what your actual problem is? This is what I think you might want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \begin{center}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                [xshift=-3cm,ultra thick,node distance=1cm]
                \node[](c1)[xshift=0cm]{$5$};
                \node[](c2)[xshift=3cm]{$4$};
                \node[](r1)[xshift=+2cm,yshift=+4cm]{$7$};
                \node[](r2)[xshift=-2cm,yshift=3cm]{$6$};
                \node[](r3)[xshift=-5.4cm,yshift=-3cm]{${3}$};    
                \node[](r4)[xshift=0cm,yshift=-4cm]{${2}$};    
                \node[](r5)[xshift=5cm,yshift=-5cm]{${1}$};     
                
                %nodes of arrow                     
                \node[](s)[xshift=-7cm,yshift=3cm,label={[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm]\huge{s}}]{};    
                \node[](s0)[xshift=-7cm,yshift=-5cm]{};
                                            
                \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (c2);
                \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (r3);
                \draw[<->,black] (r1)-- (r4);
                \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r1);
                \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r3);
                \draw[<->,black] (r2)-- (r4);
                \draw[<->,black] (r3)-- (r4);
                \draw[<->,black] (r3)-- (c1);
                \draw[<->,black] (r4)-- (r5);
                \draw[<->,black] (r5)-- (c1);
                \draw[<->,black] (r5)-- (c2);
                \draw[->,black](r3)edge[in=-20,out=60,loop below]node[below right]{}();
                \draw[->,black](r5)edge[in=-20,out=60,loop below]node[below right]{}();     
                
                %arrow plus labels      
                \draw[->,black] (s0)-- (s) node[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm,label={[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-7.5cm]\huge1},label={[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-5.5cm]\huge2},label={[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-3.5cm]\huge3},label={[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-1.5cm]\huge4}]{};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{ }
            \label{}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, I have deleted some parts of the code. I put circles around each number and colored them red. so it was defined. sorry for the confusion. Thanks!